How to create a dataflow template which can bypass Oracle database connection at time of template creation?
My requirement is to connect to Oracle OnPrem database from dataflow, read data and store on GCS. I am using python script for that. I am creating creating dataflow classic template through git action and script uses JDBC connector, currently it is failing to create the template as database connection from github runner is not allowed. So, I want to bypass the connection during template creation and script should make connection only when actual dataflow job will run.
I tried using other connector like cx_Oracle, jaybedebeapi and with that able to bypass connection but it fails at dataflow job with error "no matching distribution found" for above said modules. Need resolution for the said issue.
`
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, SetupOptions, ValueProvider
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.value_provider import RuntimeValueProvider, ValueProvider
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import WriteToJdbc, ReadFromJdbc
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText, WriteToText
from apache_beam.transforms import PTransform
from apache_beam.transforms.core import DoFn, ParDo
import logging
from apache_beam import coders


class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--jdbc_url',
            help='jdbc_url'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--driver_class_name',
            help='Driver class name'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--username',
            help='Username'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--password',
            help='Password'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--table_name',
            help='table_name'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--query',
            help='query'
        )


class ReadFromJdbccustom():
    def __init__(self, jdbc_url, driver_class_name, username, password, query, table_name):
        self.jdbc_url = jdbc_url
        self.driver_class_name = driver_class_name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.query = query
        self.table_name = table_name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.datasource = ReadFromJdbc(
                    driver_class_name=self.driver_class_name.get(),
                    jdbc_url=self.jdbc_url.get(),
                    username=self.username.get(),
                    password=self.password.get(),
                    query=self.query.get(),
                    table_name=self.table_name.get())
        return self.datasource

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass
        #self.datasource.close()

class ReadFromJdbcWithFn(DoFn):
    def __init__(self, jdbc_url: ValueProvider, driver_class_name: ValueProvider, username: ValueProvider, password: ValueProvider, query: ValueProvider, table_name: ValueProvider):
        self.jdbc_url = jdbc_url
        self.driver_class_name = driver_class_name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.query = query
        self.table_name = table_name

    def process(self, element):
        with ReadFromJdbccustom(
                    self.driver_class_name,
                    self.jdbc_url,
                    self.username,
                    self.password,
                    self.query,
                    self.table_name) as datasource:
             for row in datasource:
                processed_data = element + row[0]
                yield processed_data

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, save_main_session=True)
options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    oracle_data = (
        p | 'Start' >> beam.Create([None]) | "Read from Oracle" >> beam.ParDo(ReadFromJdbcWithFn(
            options.jdbc_url,
            options.driver_class_name,
            options.username,
            options.password,
            options.query,
            options.table_name
        )
        )
    )

`

Rather than classic dataflow template, try with dataflow flex template as at the time of deployment of classic template, actual pipeline gets executed.
